# Как заполнить поле класса через сеттер

Tags: php

Как заполнить поле класса через сеттер? Зачем вообще нужны сеттеры и геттеры, если можно работать с полями напрямую, и код будет более читаем, и ресурсы экономятся?

Comment: Если все свойства класса публичные - зачем сеттеры и геттеры? - Не нужны. И это не значит что надо все свойства делать публичными. Но если свойство приватное а его получить надо вне класса (как свойство объекта) - нужны сеттеры/геттеры.

Comment: Спасибо, понял зачем нужны сеттеры, но вопрос остаётся открытым, такая задача

Comment: да, не используйте эти буржуйские технологии. Пишите чистый код напрямую. Долой сеттеры!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Example 
{
  private $field;

  public function setField($value)
  {
    $this->field = $value;
  }
  public function getField()
  {
    return $this->field;
  }
}

$obj = new Example;
$obj->setField(123);
echo $obj->getField();
```